# HoloEverywhere method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to use [HoloEverywhere 1.3.2](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) with Maven build system in IntelliJ. Below is the code from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.xyz.holocheck"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
              android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock">
        <activity android:name="HoloActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and the code for HoloActivity is as below

```
public class HoloActivity extends SActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

when I compile the code I getting the below errors

```
C:\Users\abc\IdeaProjects\HoloCheck\target\unpack\apklibs\com.github.christopheversieux_holoeverywhere-library_apklib_1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\src\com\WazaBe\HoloEverywhere\sherlock\SActivity.java:[322,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] C:\Users\abc\IdeaProjects\HoloCheck\target\unpack\apklibs\com.github.christopheversieux_holoeverywhere-library_apklib_1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\src\com\WazaBe\HoloEverywhere\sherlock\SExpandableListActivity.java:[323,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] C:\Users\abc\IdeaProjects\HoloCheck\target\unpack\apklibs\com.github.christopheversieux_holoeverywhere-library_apklib_1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\src\com\WazaBe\HoloEverywhere\sherlock\SListActivity.java:[322,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] C:\Users\abc\IdeaProjects\HoloCheck\target\unpack\apklibs\com.github.christopheversieux_holoeverywhere-library_apklib_1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\src\com\WazaBe\HoloEverywhere\sherlock\SPreferenceActivity.java:[323,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I am also using ActionbarSherlock and have added it as dependency in pom.xml.

**My Question**

Why I am getting error while compiling the code?

Comment: Did you notice that it say ...holoeverywhere-library_apklib_1.3.1-SNAPSHOT? Instead of 1.3.2

Comment: @DandreAllison Thnks for the comment. But frankly I abandoned using Maven, after wasting almost 8 days. 1. Android team does not upload to Maven Central 2. You need to install the Android Maven plugnin and copy the SDK to Maven repo, that too fails for trivial reasons 3. Security of download from Maven Central is questionable. I read Sonatype is trying to make money out of security of content downloaded from Maven Central. It is more of a hassel than any advantage. Instead download Lib using IntelliJ and add it as dependency. IntelliJ-Idea showers lot of love on developer that too for free.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no onCreate() method in SActivity class. Please check it.